# Expression Engine MSM with 2 main sites and 5 subdomains

Tags: multiple-sites

Our main question is how do we configure Expression Engine to handle 2 main site and 5 subdomains using Multi Site Manager (MSM), keeping in mind that the development version of the main site (ee28.sode.org) is currently running as a subdomain.

We currently have three sites running on two different versions of Expression Engine on Nexcess eep-100 hosting plan. These three sites have three respective folders on the server.

## 1. *www.sode.org*

- EE1
- set up as the master domain for which Nexcess creates a directory
  at the root level of the account
- This site is live
- This site will become members.sode.org running on EE1 so we don't have to recreate
  the membership portal

## 2. *www.plungede.org*

- EE2.8 (base EE install for Multi Site Manager MSM)
- set up as a secondary domain for which Nexcess creates a directory at the root level of the account
- This site is live

## 3. *ee28.sode.org*

- EE2.8  (added with MSM to the plungede.org install. Shares system folder w/ plunge and and templates are inside  plungede.org folder on server
- Set up as secondary domain for which Nexcess creates a directory at the root level of the account
- This site is in development site
- This will become www.sode.org
- This will hold the 5 microsites (subdomains).

  - They are each set up as a subdomain and Nexcess creates a directory for each inside the secondary domain directory of sode.org on the server.

Is it possible  to configure Expression Engine to handle 2 main site and 5 subdomains, keeping in mind that the development version of the main site (ee28.sode.org) is currently running as a subdomain.

Please feel free to ask questions for clarification as we are a little confused ourselves!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in understanding how MSM works.

MSM doesn't really care what you call your sites, www.domain.com or something.domain.com so technically there are no "main" sites.

If you look at a typical folder structure for an MSM setup you may have in the root folder:

index.php (usually the site that EE is installed in, eg www.mysite.com)

/site2/index.php (an MSM site with full domain mapping, eg www.site2.com)

/site3/index.php (an MSM site with subdomain mapping, eg site3.mysite.com)

/site4/index.php (an MSM site with subdomain mapping, eg site4.mysite.com)

/site5/index.php (an MSM site with subdomain mapping, eg site5.mysite.com)

/site6/index.php (an MSM site with subdomain mapping, eg site6.mysite.com)

/site7/index.php (an MSM site with subdomain mapping, eg site7.mysite.com)

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you. It helps to know MSM treats subdomains and domains as different sites and ignores the sub domain issue.